# how to install setuptools for Python 2.7.1 on Mac OS X Tiger?

Tags: python, macos, setuptools

i've got a problem when trying to install setuptools on Mac OS X Tiger

the current version of python is 2.7.1

```
...:~/Desktop usrusr$ python -V
Python 2.7.1
```

i downloaded this egg setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg, and followed the instructions. unfortunately i'm getting an error:

```
...:~/Desktop usrusr$ sudo sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg: line 3: exec: python2.7: not found
```

i tried to build and install setuptools from source, which placed setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg in the *correct* directory - in my case it's /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

but when i'm trying to do the same (sudo sh ...), i'm getting the same error - line 3: exec: python2.7: not found

please, help!

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When you installed python, you didn't end up with a `python2.7` symlink to your python binary for some reason.  Creating one somewhere in your path should work.

Comment: thanks a lot! the problem was actually slightly different - i had a symlink, but i didn't have /usr/local/bin in my $PATH
everything working well now